# Rails Bootstrap wont use tabulation. (This is a Rails - CSS issue)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

As allways, I think I miss some basic thing, but I hope you can help.

I have a site in development. I chose bootstrap as a basic CSS framework. I tried to build up a tab on a view.

```
<div class="text_area">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#tarot" data-toggle="tab">Tarot Jóslás</a></li>
    <li><a href="#iching" data-toggle="tab">I Ching Jóslás</a></li>
    <li><a href="#igennem" data-toggle="tab">Igen Nem Jóslás</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tarot">1
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="iching">2
  </div>    

  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="igennem">3s
  </div>
</div>
```

With this view, my tabs wont tabulate. Yesterday it worked correctly, and now it stacked.
I have checked an other projects and if I start a server I miss some of my files:

This is what I have on the other project:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/sessions.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/users.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is what I have now:

```
 <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Several lines missing. Is this the source of problem? Or what do I miss?
All helps much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was clear. I've forget to add the required code:

```
//= require bootstrap
```

to:

Just above the call to //= require_tree . within app/assets/javascripts/application.js.

Credits goes to [Tim K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43043/tim-k) because of:

[the "bootstrap-sass" doesn't work with rails 3.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715470/the-bootstrap-sass-doesnt-work-with-rails-3-2-2)